# U.N. Group of Eminent Persons: membership of 2001 group and general purpose?

Tags: united-nations

The Wikipedia article for Harvard-professor [Tu Weiming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_Weiming) mentions that he was appointed to a Group of Eminent Persons to facilitate the Dialogue among Civilizations in 2001 by the then Secretary-General of the United Nations.

Who else was a member of that body and which ideas were represented? (I take it that Prof. Tu represented Confucianism, because he is commonly identified as a Neo-Confucian scholar.)

I noticed that the U.N. also sponsors other Groups of Eminent Persons, such as [this](http://www.ctbto.org/the-treaty/article-xiv-conferences/2013-conference-on-facilitating-the-entry-into-force-of-the-comprehensive-nuclear-test-ban-treaty-united-nations-new-york-usa/group-of-eminent-persons-gem/) recent one whose mandate covers comprehensive nuclear test-bans. So I am also wondering whether this kind of expert involvement is an official part of how the U.N. normally arrives at its recommendations.

Comment: "how the U.N. normally arrives at its recommendations" - corruption, nepotism, bowing to dictatorships and anti-capitalism seem the most fruitful approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Group of Eminent Persons" is just a fancy way to describe getting a bunch of leaders in a given field together to brainstorm ideas.  Another term for this is "think tank," although that implies a longer-lasting group than a GEM.  In this case, the UN creates them as necessary to generate reports, which are then delivered to the Assembly.  Beyond announcing whatever conclusions they reach (and thus potentially informing a country's vote), they have no say in the UN's processes.

That particular group is discussed [here](http://classic.weltethos.org/dat-english/00-un.htm), along with the presentation speech, and the full report is available in PDF form [here](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic241166.files/TuCrossingDivide.pdf).  The list of participants is on page 2 of the PDF, and Tu Weiming is listed as one of the two people representing China.  Other participants represented other countries, including France, the US, Germany, Egypt, and so on.  While I wouldn't be surprised if he was chosen for his role as a Neo-Confucian scholar, that isn't directly reflected in the report, nor is it primarily about religion.